# How does Ruby distinguish between Method and Method=(parameter) (same name getter/setter methods)?

Tags: ruby, class, object

Given the following code:

```
class Animal
  def noise=(noise)
    @noise = noise
  end

  def noise
    @noise
  end
end

animal1 = Animal.new
animal1.noise = "Moo!"
puts animal1.noise

animal2 = Animal.new
animal2.noise = "Quack!"
puts animal2.noise
```

How does Ruby distinguish between noise and noise = (parameter)? Usually when two methods are written out in Ruby, the latest one wins out, but just wondering how it is possible for two methods of the same name to be written in this fashion, without one overwriting the other.

Comment: In one case the name of the method includes the equal sign: `:noise=`. Ruby allows you to write that as `noise=(other)` or `noise = other`. The latter is sometimes called, "syntactic sugar".

Comment: Where do you get the idea that they have the same name? They are clearly different: the string after the `def` and before the parameters is the name.

Comment: I got it from the fact that animal1.noise = "Moo!" and puts animal1.noise have an identical string (animal1.noise). I assumed everything after the equal signs to be a part of the method, not the method name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those are two different method names. In ruby it is a idiom that a method name with a `=` is a assignment method. When the interpretor is parsing the source code it sees the difference between

```
def noise
```

and

```
def noise=
```

If you were to take out the `=` in that first noise method you would observe the behavior that you expected. If you are really interested in the ins and outs of how method look up in ruby works (and you should be since its really important for every ruby programmer to know) checkout this [post](http://pascalbetz.github.io/ruby/2016/03/14/lookup-path/)

Answer (score 3):

> How does Ruby distinguish between `noise` and `noise = (parameter)`?

By the fact that they have different names. `noise=(parameter)` (correctly defined with no spaces and often referred to as a *setter method* because it *sets* @noise) is not the same as `noise` (often referred to as a *getter method* because it *gets* @noise).

The `=` is part of the name of the method. When using `=` at the end of a method name, you can then call the method with a parameter to *set* @noise:

```
animal.noise=('baaaa')
```

but Ruby's [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) allows you to simply write.

```
animal.noise = 'baaaa'
```

then to to *get* back the value of `@noise` we call the `noise` method:

```
animal.noise #=> 'baaaa'
```